# Upgrade bundled TypeScript Compiler for IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, typescript

Is it possible to upgrade the Bundled TypeScript Compiler for IntelliJ?  Currently, it lists 1.8.10.  Or am I relegated to using the "Custom directory"?

Comment: You probably need to install typescript and then select that as custom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can only point to the custom typescript directory.  Eventually WebStorm will release an update that will bundle the latest version, but until then, it's custom for us.